# Running more than one spark applications in cluster, all spark applications are not running optimally as some are getting completed sooner

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am running 20 spark applications on an emr cluster of 2 workers and 1 master node with c5.24xlarge instances, thus I have 192 cores in total and 1024 gb ram in total.
Each application is processing around 1.5gb data!
I am having dynamic allocation as enabled and other spark configuration as following!

```
spark.executor.memory = 9000M,
spark.executor.memoryoverhead = 1000M,
spark.executor.cores = 5,
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 40,
spark.dynamicallocation.initialExecutor = 2,
spark.dynamicallocation.maxExecutor  = 10,
spark.dynamicallocation.minExecutor  = 10,
spark.dynamicallocation.executorIdleTimeOut = 60s,
spark.dynamicallocation.SchedulerBacklogTimeout = 120s,
spark.driver.memory = 9000M,
spark.driver.memoryoverhead = 1000M,
spark.driver.cores = 9
```

And spark.default.parallelism =384 (This is decided by emr, not sure how it is decided)

These, I have set at the cluster level which means for all 20 applications this would be the spark confs properties.

having these configurations settings, I can see that only few applications are getting completed in around 20 mins, and around 10 applications keep running for more than 2 hours with only one task running and for some around 10.

Questions:

1. Why other applications are not getting completed like other
   completed one?
2. I am giving partitions count as 40, then why around 350 tasks
   are being added (is it because of parallelism) for each application.
3. the data for each task is showing like 1.4 gb for task 0 , then
   1.3gb for task 1 and so on, is  that how data is shown for task pane or data is not being divided properly? (Although I can see in event matrics that partitions seem to be of same size, execution timewise.)
4. Data to executor in executor summary tab is showing more
   than for 1.4 gb, which is sum of all input for each task, but its
   processing 1.5gb only (from spark sql tab), so it means that's how
   data is shown in executor pane?

Thanks!

Comment: Each spark application is just reading a json file of 1.5 gb and writing it into parquet file, so no big transforamtions and all, although json seems to be pretty nested but the stage to read schema, seems to be pretty fast as three stages are there in total for the job, stage 0 for reading , stage 2 for writitng so stage 1 should be for reading schema, right? and stage 1 only is getting completed very fast (so I guess we are good here) And all spark applications have one job only as described.

Comment: you could try using the fair scheduler

Comment: yes, I am using fair scheduler only!